# C# ASMX webservice semi -permanant storage requirement

Tags: persistence, asmx, isolatedstorage

I'm writing a mock of a third-party web service to allow us to develop and test our application.

I have a requirement to emulate functionality that allows the user to submit data, and then at some point in the future retrieve the results of processing on the service.  What I need to do is persist the submitted data somewhere, and retrieve it later (not in the same session).  What I'd like to do is persist the data to a database (simplest solution), but the environment that will host the mock service doesn't allow for that.

I tried using IsolatedStorage (application-scoped), but this doesn't seem to work in my instance.  (I'm using the following to get the store...

```
IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Application | 
    IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
```

I guess my question is (bearing in mind the fact that I understand the limitations of IsolatedStorage) how would I go about getting this to work?  If there is no consistent way to do it, I guess I'll have to fall back to persisting to a specific file location on the filesystem, and all the pain of permission setting that entails in our environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer.

For the pruposes of dev and test, I realised it would be easiest to limit the lifetime of the persisted objects, and use

```
HttpRuntime.Cache
```

to store the objects.  This has just enough flexibility to cope with my situation.